# How to detect language from audio in python?

Tags: python-3.x, audio, language-detection

I have tried using FFMPEG for audio extraction from video.
How to transcribe speech to text and detect the language?

I have tried using ,
Myspokenlangauge
Google cloud -speech to text api

Answer (score 0):

You can use speech to text to detect the words.
Send the words to google translate which automatically detects the language.
Then you can web-scrape the auto detected tag.

Comment: okay , i have tried using that. Is there any other way ?

Comment: speech to text requires apriori knowledge of the language... otherwise it won't work well!

Answer (score 0):

You can take the text from speech to text engine using one of the most used languages for your use case.

Create a labelled dataset to train NLP model - for text classification.

Use this model to detect the text coming out of STT engine.